# Reduce number tez mappers during runtime

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

In map reduce engine, we can control the number of mappers using the following config:

> mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum

How to achieve the same using tez?
My goal is to load csv data into a table at the same time keeping the order of data. As I understand, if number of mappers is more than one it will not guarantee order.